# Jenkins multijob with Selenium and Cucumber

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I have a Parent Job that runs other jobs in parallel (Selenium tests with Cucumber-jvm reports).
Each parallel job runs some tests and when all finishes, the QA team grabs the reports of each (parallel) job and merge them all manually.

Is it possible to make the parent job to receive all the logs and generate a full report after all parallel tests ends?

Comment: what kind of reports do you have and how do you create them matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can store tests results from child jobs as artifacts of jobs, and next you can copy artifacts to parent job when completed e.g. to directory `test_reports`.
Next on your job you can use: Publish Junit test result report and you can add all tests from `test_reports` directory, e.g.: `test_reports/**/*.xml`.